# Disable TLS1.0 and TLS 1.1

Tags: php, apache, ssl, cpanel, tls1.2

I am using Apache and i have access of cPanel. I want to disable TLS1.0. I have  no idea how to do this. Can this done via cPanel.

Is there is any option how to do that? or Where i need to change that.

Comment: Do you have WHM access or just cPanel access?

Comment: i dont know about WHM?  i do have Cpanel access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cannot be done via cPanel but only through WHM and only the server administrator can do that. If you do not have WHM access then there is no way to achieve this by only having regular cPanel access. You can ask your hoster to do that for you instead. Not sure they will accept it though.